# Extract data from HTTP JSON

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and I'm trying to extract data from a URL. 
My component code is:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, OnInit }      from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {ArticleService} from "../services/ArticleService";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-article',
    templateUrl: './article.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./article.component.css'],
    providers: [ArticleService]

})
export class ArticleComponent implements OnInit {

    article: JSON;

    constructor(
        private ArticleService: ArticleService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.ArticleService.getArticle(+params['id']))
            .subscribe(art => {
                this.article = art;
            });

    }

}
```

My Article.service.ts is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    private apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getArticle(id: number) {
        const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${id}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

If I use `console.log(this.article)` inside the .subscribe() block, it displays the object but displays undefined if used outside, so I can't use the data in my html template.

Comment: What do you mean with "outside"? "outside" is probably executed before the data is available. The Data only becomes available when the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` was called.

Comment: I meant after "this.router.params". Sorry if it wasn't understandable. What should I do to use this data to display it in the html template?

Comment: After `this.router.params` is executed before the data is available. You probably just want to use `?.` like `article?.name` to avoid error messages when Angular resolves bindings before the data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator

```
<div>{{article?.name}}</div>
```

or wrap the part that depends on `article` with `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="article">
  <div>{{article.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making an interface for your article rather than assigning to type JSON. I'm not even aware that that is a build in type.

Comment: Thanks also for your comment, I changed it to an interface